# Ember intermittent acceptance test failures that pass when run alone

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I'm hoping to get some clues about why I have intermittent test failures. I have an acceptance test that fails when I run the entire module, but all of the individual tests pass when they are run alone. The issue seems to have something to do with using a loop around assertions because I have two different tests that fail and both have a forEach loop something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from "dwellconnect-app/tests/helpers/start-app";

var things;

module('Acceptance | something', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    this.application = startApp();
    things = [
      Ember.Object({someProperty: '1'}),
      Ember.Object({someProperty: '2'}),
      Ember.Object({someProperty: '3'}),
      Ember.Object({someProperty: '4'}),
    ]

  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(this.application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Something', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(4);

  visit('/something');

  andThen(function() {
    // Check that each thing is on the page
    things.forEach(function(thing) {
      var someSelector = 'span:contains("' + thing.someProperty + '")';
      assert.equal(find(someSelector).length, 1, 'Shows each thing');
    });
  });
});
```

First of all, is there something wrong with this approach and if so, what is the correct way to build a set of assertions around an array of data. If not, what else could be causing the issue? Even if you can only provide possible scenarios for intermittent failures, it might lead me in the right direction. Right now there are no errors and this is making me crazy. I'm not sure Sherlock Holmes could find this one.

Comment: What form does the test failure take? DOM elements missing? Intermittent test failures like this are normally caused by timing (asserting about the DOM while it's still being manipulated) or state leakage between tests

Comment: The failure is missing computed property DOM elements.  The values are blank.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into this as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exactly and it was a combination of changing many things.  However, I can tell you that the method of looping I described above is valid and should work just fine.